# NSDate for today at midnight

Tags: date, logic, nsdate, nspredicate

I am setting up an NSPredicate for a fetch to Core Data which is set up like so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", todaysDate, tomorrowsDate];
```

I need `todaysDate` to be today at 00:00:00, and I need `tomorrowsDate` to be today at 23:59:59.

I can't set `todaysDate` equal to `[NSDate date]` and then manipulate the hours, minutes, and seconds with NSDateComponents because `[NSDate date]` gives me a date which is 5 hours ahead of my local actual time (so if it's 11:00 pm here on May 6th, then `[NSDate date]` would give me "2014-05-07 04:00:00 +0000", but I still need it to think that it is May 6th, not 7th!).

How can I manipulate the tools I have in Xcode to consistently get my variable `todaysDate` to be today at midnight, and `tomorrowsDate` to be a second before midnight strikes tomorrow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rangeOfUnit:...` method of `NSCalendar` is a convenient method to
 compute the start of the current day and the start of tomorrow
*in your local time zone*:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *todaysDate;
NSDate *tomorrowsDate;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&todaysDate interval:&interval forDate:now];
tomorrowsDate = [todaysDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
```

so that you can use it in the predicate with `>=` and `<`:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date < %@)", todaysDate, tomorrowsDate]
```

to fetch all objects of the current day.

---

*Remark:* Don't let the `NSLog()` output of `NSDate` objects confuse you.
`NSDate` represents an absolute point in time and knows nothing about time zones.
`NSLog(@"%@", todaysDate)` prints the date according to the GMT time zone and not in your local time zone.

To print the dates according to your time zone, use `p todaysDate` in the debugger console (instead of `po`),
or print

```
[todaysDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]
```

Comment: Just tried it, and the only entities that are being fetched are ones where the `date` variable is May 7th (all of the time values for my entities are midnight). So this tells me that my range is from 5 am May 6th to 5am May 7th.. Is the predicate using GMT as well then??

Comment: @EAB: The predicate just compares the dates (which are seconds since Jan 1, 2001). Perhaps your objects were stored with the time 00:00 in GMT and not in your local time zone?? Then try `[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];` to make the start/end of day calculation use GMT as well.

Comment: haha wow. I'm not sure what just happened, but that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
- (NSDate *)dateWithDate:(NSDate *)date Hour:(NSInteger)hour Minute:(NSInteger)minute Second:(NSInteger)second {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];
    components.hour = hour;
    components.minute = minute;
    components.second = second;
    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Example:

```
NSDate *beginningOfDay = [self dateWithDate:[NSDate date] Hour:0 Minute:0 Second:0];
NSDate *endOfDay = [self dateWithDate:[NSDate date] Hour:23 Minute:59 Second:59];
```

Comment: this seems like it should work, but I am still getting GMT value I think... todaysDate and tomorrowsDate both still seem to be 5 hours ahead according to NSLog and the Predicate comparison

Answer (score 1):

Swift:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

//tip:NSCalendarUnit can be omitted, but with the presence of it, you can take advantage of Xcode's auto-completion
var comps = cal.components(NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | .MonthCalendarUnit | .DayCalendarUnit | .HourCalendarUnit | .MinuteCalendarUnit | .SecondCalendarUnit, fromDate: NSDate()) 
comps.hour = 0
comps.minute = 0
comps.second = 0

let todaysDate = cal.dateFromComponents(comps)!
let tomorrowsDate = NSDate(timeInterval: 86399, sinceDate: todaysDate)
```

Objective-C:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; 

NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components: (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate: [NSDate date]];    
[comps setHour:0]; 
[comps setMinute:0]; 
[comps setSecond:0];

NSDate *todaysDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
NSDate *tomorrowsDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: 86399 sinceDate:todaysDate];
```